# dealing with additional file and the od2trips tool

Tags: python, sumo

I have a trip file generated by the od2trips tool which is going to be used in the duaIterate.py. To make my interest changes in that trip file, an additional file is needed which I can not find its corresponding option in the od2trips.
I appreciate any suggestion.
Best, Ali

Comment: You need to write that file manually for instance to define vehicle types.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I found it a few days after my question by adding the vehicle definition to the route file manually, as you said.